# Communicate between my UWP app and my rfxtrx433e

Tags: usb, win-universal-app, communication

I'm writing a UWP (universal Windows Platform) app to communicate with my RFXTRX433e. I'm able to connect to the correct serial device but not able to write anything. Actually the methode for writing looks to work (I don't get any exceprion) but it seems that my USB device doesn't get the info (light is not switched on when sending the packet).

```
var myDevices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqsFilter, null);
            using (SerialDevice serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices.First(o => o.Name == "RFXtrx433").Id))
            {   
                //Get the reset package
                var reset = ProtocolManager.ResetPackage;                   
                using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream))
                {
                      writer.WriteBuffer(buffer.AsBuffer());
                }
```

Have someone any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final solution:

```
   using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream))
    {
         writer.WriteBuffer(reset.GetPacket().AsBuffer());
         await writer.StoreAsync();
         await writer.FlushAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting a not implemented exception in the FlushAsync line.

Answer (score 0):

The DataWriter is using an internal buffer to retain data until your packet is ready.

The data are committed to the stream only when calling the [DataWriter.StoreAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.storeasync.aspx) method. You can also call [DataWriter.FlushAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.flushasync.aspx) to complete the write operation

Comment: Thanks for your replay however, when I add await writer.FlushAsync();
I get the following exception: The method or operation is not implemented

And When I used the await writer.StoreAsync();
Nothing happend..

Comment: The solution was to use both. First I had to use the store async and then the FlushAsync.